# How to use multiple Locators with different TrackingFunction in Manipulate?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, locator

I am trying to use `TrackingFunction` with `Locator` inside `Manipulate`, and it works fine with a single `Locator`, but it fails as soon as I use multiple `Locators`. Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:

Suppose I want to have two `Locator`s on a circle: one shall be restricted to the circle's boundary, the other one shall be restricted to the whole disk (i.e. boundary plus inside). Here is how I tried to solve that:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Circle[],PlotRange ->2],
    {{pt,{0,1}},Locator,TrackingFunction->(pt=Normalize[#];&)},
    {{pt2,{1,0}},Locator,TrackingFunction->(pt2=#/Max[Norm[#],1];&)}]
```

The `TrackingFunction`s, however, seem to have no effect, as can be seen in the following image:

[image: Output of Manipulate]

If I delete one of the two locators, the `TrackingFunction` works. How can I use both `Locator`s at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a different construction to create multiple `Locator`s:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> 2], {{pt, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}, 
  Locator,
  TrackingFunction -> (p |-> {
      pt[[1]] = Normalize[p[[1]]],
      pt[[2]] = p[[2]]/Max[Norm[p[[2]]], 1]}
    )}]
```

In this case, `pt` is a list of the locations of each `Locator`. Our `TrackingFunction` can then act on this list (called `p` in our function) and set different constraints for each point in the list.

The documentation doesn't appear to suggest that you can do multiple `Locator`s any other way, so I'm assuming it's unsupported.