# Passing control values out of nested Manipulates

Tags: manipulate, scoping

I am building a "batch photo cropper" UI.

I have a list of images to crop, and I can use `Manipulate` to make a nice cropping UI for each one:

```
Table[
 With[{im = im},
  Manipulate[
   HighlightImage[im, BoundingRegion@{p1, p2}, ImageSize -> 100],
   {p1, Locator},
   {p2, Locator},
   Button["Crop", Export["foo.jpg", ImageTrim[im, {p1, p2}]]]
   ]
  ]
  ,
  {im, ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"][[1 ;; 4]]}
]
```

[image: batch-photo-crop]

Now I would like to add a `Crop All` button, which would crop and save each image.

But I'm not sure how to pass each inner `Manipulate`'s controls to an outer `Button`.

Here is a baby example of the behavior I'm looking for:

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{
   Manipulate[a, {a, 0, 1}],
   Manipulate[b, {b, 0, 1}]
   }
 ,
 Button["print", Print[a, b]]
 ]
```

The problem is that the `print` button prints `ab`, not the numeric values from the inner `Manipulate`s. I would like to "bubble" those out, but I'm not sure how.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`LocalizeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalizeVariables.html) option of [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Manipulate[a, {a, 0, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
   , Manipulate[b, {b, 0, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
   }]
 , Button["print", Print[{a, b}]]
 ]
```

If you do not want the variable definitions to spill out of the outer `Manipulate` then wrap in [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html).

```
Remove[a, b];
DynamicModule[
 {a, b}
 , Manipulate[
  ...
  ]
 ]
```

Your `"TestImage"` example uses a list instead of individual variables.  The [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) on each of the `Manipulate` controls can be used to update the list without creating variable for each value.

```
DynamicModule[{c = Range[.2, .8, .2]}
 , Column[{
   Button["Print", Print[c], ImageSize -> Large]
   , Multicolumn[
    Manipulate[
       a
       , {
        {a, c[[#]], Subscript["c", #]}, 0, 1
        , TrackingFunction -> {None, Automatic, 
          Function[{v, e}, c[[#]] = v; e = v;, HoldRest]}
        }
       ] & /@ Range[Length@c]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps, thank you! One last question: how would you tweak your example to use indexed variables like `a[[1]]` and `a[[2]]`, instead of `a` and `b`, so that I could work with a list?

Comment: @ConvexMartian See update.

Comment: WOW, thank you! I didn't know about `TrackingFunction`. This is great!

Comment: Can I ask why the `HoldRest` is needed in the "updater" function? It still works without it.

Comment: Ah, without `HoldRest`, the Messages window complains: `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 0.645.` Thank you!

Comment: Just a note that when I adapted this solution to my image-cropping problem, I encountered a "bug" where TrackingFunction doesn't work with multiple Locators, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/247116/how-to-use-multiple-locators-with-different-trackingfunction-in-manipulate).