# TrackingFunction does not work when more than one Locator in Manipulator

Tags: manipulate, locator

[TrackingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html)  example

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> 2], 
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> (pt = #/Max[Norm[#], 1]; &)}]
```

works

but when I add one Locator, no constraint is imposed on two Locators.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> 2]
 
 , {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> (pt = {#[[1]], 0}; &)}
 , {{pt1, {0, 2}}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> (pt1 = {#[[1]], 2}; &)}
 ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to use multiple Locators with different TrackingFunction in Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/247116/125)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a "LocatorPane" for several locators. But it seems simpler to use an array of locators like:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> 2]
 , {{pt, {{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> (pt = {{#[[1, 1]], 0}, {#[[2, 1]], 1.5}}; &)}
 ]
```

[image]